# 端末エミュレータ(konsole)で日本語に使われるフォントの設定方法

Tags: linux, font

KDE 上で konsole を使っています. "Edit current profile" から設定できるフォントとしては[fantasque sans mono](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans) を指定しています.

`.kde/share/apps/konsole/mydefault.profile` は以下のような感じです.

```
[Appearance]
ColorScheme=mycolor
Font=Fantasque Sans Mono,12,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

さて、このフォントは日本語で使われるグリフはカバーしていないのですが,konsole 上ではきちんと日本語が表示されます.ということは日本語（その他 fantasque sans のカバーしていない）文字の表示に際しては,別のフォントが参照されているということになるのだと思います.

このフォントを指定することは出来るでしょうか.
これは,gVim でいう `guifontwide` の設定をしたいというのに近いです.

現在は KDE (Kubuntu) + Konsole という環境ですが,その他の環境についての情報も,僕自身が参考に出来るほか,後から参照する際に有用となりうると思いますので,お寄せいただければと思います.

Comment: 「英語版ではoff topic...」という文を削除しました: 「よくない質問」というネガティブなバイアスがかからないようにするため

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Konsole`の設定でフォント形状をノーマルやボールドに指定すると、日本語もそれに合わせて変更されると思います。これは`Linux`(に限りませんが)が指定されたフォント名をそのまま利用するのではなくて、フォント名にマッチしたいくつかのフォントから言語などに応じて最適なフォントを選ぶためのようです。

このフォントの選択ルールは`~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`を修正することで変えることが出来ます。書式については以下のような記事が参考になります。

[26.2. フォントのインストールと設定](https://www.suse.com/ja-jp/documentation/sles10/book_sle_reference/data/sec.x11.fontconfig.html)

[Ubuntu - gnome-terminalで英語と日本語のフォントを別々に指定する（fonts.conf） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/q1701/items/00418d17ec97cc2768f7)

[Fontconfig - Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig)

また、`fc-match`コマンドで、実際にフォント名を与えて、そこから選択されるフォントの一覧(優先順位)を確認することもできます。たとえばserifを指定している場合に日本語のフォントが何になるかは

```
fc-match serif:lang=ja
```

で調べることが出来ます。この例を手元の`Ubuntu 14.04LTS`で確認すると、`Takao P明朝`と出ました。

`fonts.conf`をいじりつつ、お使いの環境で調べたいフォント名を`fc-match`でその都度確認することで、目的のフォントを表示できるようになるのではないかと思います。

---

普段は`Linux`には`ssh`で接続しているため、手元のターミナルでフォントを変更でき、この部分は気にする必要がないのですが、投稿を読んで気になったので調べてみました。より専門的な回答が得られるまでのつなぎとしてヒントになれば幸いです。